# Remove all Field Beginning with name "XX"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

An example document from a collection:

`{ "teamAlpha": { }, "teamBeta": { }, "leader_name": "leader" }`

For such document, I would like to remove all fields that starts with `"team"`. So the expected result is

`{leader_name: "leader"}`

I am currently using a function:

```
db.teamList.find().forEach(
    function(document) {
        for(var k in document) {
            if (k.startsWith('team')) {
                delete document[k];
            }
        }
        db.teamList.save(document);
    }
);
```

I am wondering if there is a better approach for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be "better" to instead determine all the possible keys beforehand and then issue a single [`"multi"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) update to remove all the keys. Depending on the available MongoDB version there would be different approaches.

### MongoDB 3.4: $objectToArray

```
let fields = db.teamList.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "fields": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
            "as": "d",
            "cond": { "$eq": [{ "$substrCP": [ "$$d.k", 0, 4 ] }, "team" ] }
          }
        },
        "as": "f",
        "in": "$$f.k"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$fields" },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$fields" } }
])
.map( d => ({ [d._id]: "" }))
.reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,curr),{})

db.teamList.updateMany({},{ "$unset": fields });
```

The `.aggregate()` statement turns the fields in the document into an array via `$objectToArray` and then applies [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to only return those where the first four letters of the "key" matched the string `"team"`. This is then processed with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to make a "unique list" of the matching fields.

The subsequent instructions merely process that list returned in the cursor into a single object like:

```
{
    "teamBeta" : "",
    "teamAlpha" : ""
}
```

Which is then passed to [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) to remove those fields from all documents.

### Earlier Versions: mapReduce

```
var fields = db.teamList.mapReduce(
  function() {
    Object.keys(this).filter( k => /^team/.test(k) )
      .forEach( k => emit(k,1) );
  },
  function() {},
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
.results.map( d => ({ [d._id]: "" }))
.reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,curr),{})  

db.teamList.update({},{ "$unset": fields },{ "multi": true });
```

Same basic thing, where the only difference demonstrated is where [`.updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) does not exist as a method we simply call [`.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) using the [`"multi"` parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) to apply to **all** matched documents. Which is all the new API call actually does.

### Beyond those Options

It certainly is not wise to iterate all documents simply to remove fields, and therefore either of the above would be the "preferred" approach. The only possible failing is that constructing the "distinct list" of keys actually exceeds the 16MB BSON limit. That is pretty extreme, but depending on the actual data it is possible.

Therefore there are essentially "two extensions" that naturally apply to the techniques:

1. **Use the "cursor" with `.aggregate()`**

   ```
   var fields = [];

   db.teamList.aggregate([
     { "$project": {
       "_id": 0,
       "fields": {
         "$map": {
           "input": {
             "$filter": {
               "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
               "as": "d",
               "cond": { "$eq": [{ "$substrCP": [ "$$d.k", 0, 4 ] }, "team" ] }
             }
           },
           "as": "f",
           "in": "$$f.k"
         }
       }
     }},
     { "$unwind": "$fields" },
     { "$group": { "_id": "$fields" } }
   ]).forEach( d => {
     fields.push(d._id);

     if ( fields.length >= 2000 ) {
       db.teamList.updateMany({},
         { "$unset": 
           fields.reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr]: "" }),{})
         }
       );
     }
   });

   if ( fields.length > 0 ) {
     db.teamList.updateMany({},
       { "$unset": 
         fields.reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr]: "" }),{})
       }
     );
   }
   ```

   Where this would essentially "batch" the number of fields as processed on the "cursor" into lots of 2000, which "should" stay well under the 16MB BSON limit as a request.
2. **Use a temporary collection with `mapReduce()`**

   ```
   db.teamList.mapReduce(
     function() {
       Object.keys(this).filter( k => /^team/.test(k) )
         .forEach( k => emit(k,1) );
     },
     function() {},
     { "out": { "replace": "tempoutput" } }
   );

   db.tempoutput.find({},{ "_id": 1 }).forEach(d => {
     fields.push(d._id);

     if ( fields.length >= 2000 ) {
       db.teamList.update({},
         { "$unset": 
           fields.reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr]: "" }),{})
         },
         { "multi": true }
       );
     }
   });

   if ( fields.length > 0 ) {
     db.teamList.update({},
       { "$unset": 
         fields.reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr]: "" }),{})
       },
       { "multi": true }
     );
   }
   ```

   Where it is again essentially the same process, except as `mapReduce` cannot output to a "cursor", you need to output to a temporary collection consisting of only the "distinct field names" and then iterate the cursor from that collection in order to process in the same "batch" manner.

Just as the similar initial approaches, these are much more performant options than iterating the whole collection and making adjustments to each document individually. It generally should not be necessary since the likelihood of any "distinct list" actually causing a single update request to exceed 16MB would indeed be extreme. But this would again be the "preferred" way to handle such an extreme case.

### General

Of course if you simply know all the field names and do not need to work them out by examining the collection, then simply write the statement with the known names:

```
db.teamList.update({},{ "$unset": { "teamBeta": "", "teamAlpha": "" } },{ "multi": true })
```

Which is perfectly valid because all the other statements are doing is working out what those names should be for you.

Comment: In my situation, the total number of records is large and it is already known that team names will never be the same. If we store the names at the very beginning it would take lots of space. Is there any other choice?

Comment: @xis I do not understand what you are saying. I just gave you three methods for dealing with the "distinct" field name selection based on the data provided in your question. In fact doing exactly as asked and not iterating each document in the process, because you do not need to. Do you not understand? Read carefully and explain thoroughly if you think something different needs to be done.

Comment: @xis If all you are saying is *"There are a lot of unique names"*, then the point is *"Is  there more than 16MB of unique names?"* Because where there is not ( and it's highly unlikely that it is true ) then the approach shown here **is** the best way. Certainly better than what you are doing.